# Is it possible to edit keywords in Lightroom with C#?

Tags: c#, adobe, lightroom

Is it possible to access an Adobe Lightroom catalog from outside with C#?

I want to get the image, then do some stuff, add some keywords, and write it back in the catalog.

Is that possible? Did anyone something like this before?

If yes, how did you do that or how would you do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I just opened one and it appears that .lrcat files are just SQLite databases. I'm going to assume that it is possible.